# In php max execution time exceed time limit

Tags: php, php-ini

I am working in localhost at port 8080 .

I am getting fatal error max execution time exceed time limit 60 seconds.

I have changed php.ini file  to  max_execution_time=1000 still I get the same error.

This is happening in wordpress plugin when I try to import.

Comment: Is your question why the error still says "60" after you've changed it to "1000", or is your question how to solve this error?

Comment: You have a problem with your code , seems like it is running on an infinite loop.

Comment: I am using port number will that be the reason. I have checked phpinfo it shows execution time 1000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `max_execution_time = -1` or you can set threw `ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);`

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Basically means it will run forever, report back if this helps.

Comment: I created htaccess it did not work and then I added the ini_set to wp_config still I get the same error

Comment: Anyway now I added the ini_set just before the line which gives the fatal error it is executing thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
```

mark above statement is a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried increase the execution time using

```
  set_time_limit(0)
```

it works thanks